# Git - Finding out who merged a feature branch to main branch

Tags: git, git-merge

We follow the feature branch method. Checkout a new branch from develop every time we work on the story and merge it back to develop after its done. We always do a rebase with develop before merging. So there is no merge commit. Now i want to figure out who merged a particular feature branch into develop. How do i find this out?

Comment: Note sure but I don't think it's possible. Always merge feature branches with non-ff!

Comment: Somehow it's possible by investigating `git reflog`, but it's volatile.

Comment: git reflog only shows your local history.

Comment: Sure, rebasing rewrites your history. Push to a remote repository sends only specified refs. So, to investigate rebases you have to have a repo where rebases were made.

Answer (score 1):

Rebase has a sense only for private branches, which are not shared between different people. So, you should merge into develop branch, don't rebase it. Otherwise it just adds more problems than solves.

Maybe it has a sense to rebase feature branches against the develop branch periodically, just to reduce number of potential conflicts during merge and to simplify history a bit.

And yes, as @CharlesB says, use `--no-ff` to track merges in history.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
git log --since="10 days ago"
```

set the time when you think the command was executed and you should get the list of users times and commits users have made in that time..

Comment: This only shows the commits that were merged to develop. I want to know who did the merge.